# I am trying to connect to MySQL with sqlalchemy and I am getting exit code 1

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

There may be an easier way but I am trying to connect to a MySQL database to be able to query with python.
This is my current code:
[image]

And these are the packages I have installed.

[image]

I am using pycharm and I have connected to the database through there but I need to be able to query code with python.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to connect to my server. I just followed the steps from w3schools. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp